# Implement CRUD functions with local data using the KendoUI Grid widget

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I need to implement KendoUI Grid widget with CRUD functions with local data. I will have some data coming from the server serialized to json. I want to load this data from the grid. When a new entry is added/ updated / deleted from the grid I want the data array to be updated accordingly. So far I have loaded the grid with data but I am not sure how to implement the create, update and destroy commands so that the changes to be updated in the data array. Here is jsfiddle sample.

http://jsfiddle.net/MwHNd/300/

I am very new to javascript and any help with working example with the jsfiddle sample will be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited the jsfiddle link sample. Now it does what I want. I noticed that sometimes after I add a new Item, Save it, then Delete it and click Save again, the delete command is called again after the save...

http://jsfiddle.net/MwHNd/408/